# ICC (14.0) cannot even compile hello-world in Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, intel

New to Linux, I just installed a Ubuntu 13.10 64 bit, with Eclipse 3.8 and intel's ICC 14.0.

The GCC come with Ubuntu is version 4.8.1.

So far ICC installed cannot even compile hello-world in Eclipse due to it cannot compile iostream header.

The `iostream` header will include another header, called `c++config.h`, stored in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/bits`

The `iostream` header itself stored in `/usr/include/c++/4.8`

The GCC compiler can compile the hello-world cpp and other c++ files perfectly, yet the ICC cannot even compile hello-world, tell me it cannot find `c++config.h` header, even if I include its path in the project.

Anyone know any work-around for this?

Comment: I have this same issue while using the newest version of the Intel compiler, `icc version 14.0.1 (gcc version 4.8.0 compatibility)`. There were no problems for me before upgrading to Ubuntu 13.10 from 13.04. I have brought this issue to the [attention](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/485017) of the Intel guys but the thread has gone stale. Perhaps some additional bug reports will motivate them to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

1. Add system include on command line

   icc -idirafter /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/ -I... -L... my.cpp
2. Permanently add it to icc.cfg

   cat /opt/intel/composer_xe_2013_sp1.1.106/bin/intel64/icc.cfg

   -idirafter /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/

I successfully used this to compile scipy.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities exist without changing too much of your setup:

1. Install an older version of GCC alongside the default one, assuming that ICC will work with some version, just maybe not the very new one you have now.
2. Install a newer version of ICC.  It looks like you may already have the latest, but perhaps there is a patch release.  I somewhat doubt it though.

This kind of thing happens fairly often when mixing and matching different compilers and standard libraries.  It helps if both are of roughly the same age.